# Unable to Install Windows 10 guest OS in Ubuntu 20.04 host using Virtualbox

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, virtualization, virtualhost

I used to work with Windows 10 guest OS in Ubuntu host machines using Virtualbox. Recently I bought a ASUS Zenbook (UX325EA-EG701TS).
I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on it and installed Virtualbox 6.1. I tried to install Windows 10 as guest OS, multiple times using different ISO files.
But every time it fails. Sometimes it fails during installation and some times during post installation, while configuring the keyboard etc.
I am not sure how to get the log messages so that I can identify the reason and possibly rectify it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do NOT use Virtualbox on Ubuntu, there's absolutely no reason to, as Linux has its native virtualization system, KVM - https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-install-kvm

Comment: Is virtualization enabled in the bios? Sometimes I forget that it needs to be enabled after I purchase a new machine.

Comment: "*every time it fails*" is vague. We really need more information than that to be able to help. If not logs, the specific error messages.

Comment: @user535733 How/Where can I check for log to know possible reasons for failure?

Comment: @Gordster: I verified it in BIOS.

Comment: @raj As per your suggestion I could successfully install Windows 10 using KVM. But is it possible to share the host folder in KVM, just like in Virtualbox. I could share guest folder using NFS. But is there a way to do the former one so that in case of Guest OS fails, my shared folder will be safe!

Comment: I'm not sure, as I never had the need to use folder sharing. But I found something about this here: https://dausruddin.com/how-to-enable-clipboard-and-folder-sharing-in-qemu-kvm-on-windows-guest/